# How to hide my internal folder structure when providing SAS Uri to public?

Tags: security, azure-storage, azure-files

when providing access to a file stored in Azure file share via SAS Uri, I need to expose my internal folder structure in the URI, e.g.
https://MYACCOUNT.file.core.windows.net/MYSHARE/everybody/can/see/my/shares/folder/structure/file.txt?SASToken=Foo

Is there a (more secure) way to provide URIs omitting the entire path?
E.g. https://MYACCOUNT.file.core.windows.net/MYSHARE?SasToken=Foo

KR,
Gerhard

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The signature required to authenticate is [generated based on multiple fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#specify-the-signature) including the path to the blob.

One way to workaround this would be to first have your users upload to a particular folder and have another process (say an Azure Function) that can move it to the right folder after.